# Show date picker in textbox in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm using react-native-datepicker to show date picker. My problem is I have two text box for start and end date. I want to show date picker when the user tap on text box.  With this code its showing date picker but I want picker to be shown when user taps on textbox. And the selected date should be bind to the textbox.

```
    <DatePicker
    style={{width: 200}}
    date={this.state.date}
    mode="date"
    placeholder="Select date"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    minDate="2016-05-01"
    maxDate="2020-12-12"
    confirmBtnText="OK"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
```

How can I achieve this? Anyhelp could be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

> function

```
_showDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true });

_hideDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false });

_handleDatePicked = date => {
    var dobValue='Select Date of Birth';
    var date = new Date(date);
    if (! isNaN(date)) {
        this.setState({ dob: date });
    }
    this._hideDateTimePicker();
```

> render

```
var dobValue='Select Date of Birth';

var date = new Date(this.state.dob);
dobValue= isNaN(date) ? this.state.dob :date.getDate() + "/"+ parseInt(date.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ date.getFullYear();


<DateTimePicker isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible} onConfirm={this._handleDatePicked} onCancel={this._hideDateTimePicker}/>

<Input style={{fontSize:16,padding:6,borderColor:'#C8C8C8',borderWidth: 1}} placeholder="Email" onChangeText={this._showDateTimePicker} value={dobValue}/>
```

Comment: I want to show picker in text input tap not on text

Comment: As per my understanding onChangeText callback will hit when we tap and we type one char in TextInput. I guess this is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Add ref to datepicker,

```
 <DatePicker
    style={{width: 200}}
    ref='datepicker'
    date={this.state.date}
    mode="date"
    placeholder="Select date"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    minDate="2016-05-01"
    maxDate="2020-12-12"
    confirmBtnText="OK"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
```

onTap of text call 
this.refs.datepicker.onPressDate();